# Undefined local variable post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, undefined, local

I write this code:

```
<% @user.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= render 'post', locals: { post: post, user: @user} %>
<% end %>
```

Then in `_post.htm.erb` I write follow code:

```
<div class="post-title">
  <img src="<%= @user.avatar.url%>" class="img-rounded post-image">
  <h4 id="post-name"><%= @user.first_name + ' ' +@user.last_name %> </h4>
  <div id="post-date"><%= post.created_at.strftime('%d %b - %k:%M') %></div>
</div>
<div class="post-content">
  <p><%= post.content %></p>
</div>
<%= render 'like', post:post %>
<li  class="post-divider"></li>
```

When I go to this page, I see follow:

```
undefined local variable or method `post'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use partial: when you pass locals to a partial as follows:

```
<%= render partial: 'post', locals: { post: post, user: @user} %>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted if its working for you so that other users can easily find it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

[From the PartialRenderer api.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

> use render **partial:** with **locals:** param or "If you're not going to be
>   using any of the options like collections or layouts, you can also use
>   the short-hand defaults of render to render partials."

```
<%= render 'post', post: post, locals: { user: @user} %>
```

Comment: From the PartialRenderer api http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html use render partial: with locals: param or "If you're not going to be using any of the options like collections or layouts, you can also use the short-hand defaults of render to render partials."